# non-inplace version of extend operator in python

Tags: python

What's a pithy pythonic non-inplace version of extend? I'm tired of writing

```
x = [ 1,2,3 ]
x.extend([4,5])
f(x)
```

Just want:

```
 f( x.extend( [4,5], inplace=False ) )
```

or whatever

Comment: `f(x + [4, 5])`? (Not *quite* the same, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6645843/3001761)

Comment: `f(x.__add__([4,5]))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about just using the `+` operator

```
def f(l):
    return l

x = [1,2,3]

>>> id(x)
48474312         # Note the id

>>> x = f(x + [4,5])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> id(x)
43637016         # Different id, that means not in-place
```